# Auto Liquidity Pool Withdraw LP Token from 0x0000

Tags: ethereum, solidity, binance

Auto Liquidity Pool Withdraw LP Token from 0x0000

I have a contract at the following:

```
https://bscscan.com/token/0x5f1b95784a033cd6842cf26eb9a9687f91ad9e78
```

It got a function which does the following

```
function swapAndLiquify(uint256 tokens) private {
   // split the contract balance into halves
    uint256 half = tokens.div(2);
    uint256 otherHalf = tokens.sub(half);

    // capture the contract's current ETH balance.
    // this is so that we can capture exactly the amount of ETH that the
    // swap creates, and not make the liquidity event include any ETH that
    // has been manually sent to the contract
    uint256 initialBalance = address(this).balance;

    // swap tokens for ETH
    swapTokensForEth(half); // <- this breaks the ETH -> HATE swap when swap+liquify is triggered

    // how much ETH did we just swap into?
    uint256 newBalance = address(this).balance.sub(initialBalance);

    // add liquidity to uniswap
    addLiquidity(otherHalf, newBalance);

    emit SwapAndLiquify(half, newBalance, otherHalf);
}
```

To date, it controlled 19% of the liquidity token at address 0x00000000000000000 and I was wondering how to withdraw or transfer the Liquidity Token to the contract owner which is my account.

```
https://bscscan.com/token/0x2f308f3c6994fc1ed690a318f07d67564dcc5aab#balances
```

Thanks